# System out of memory exception mediaelement wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I have screensaver app this app playing video and photo work normally on two hours and i get System out of memory exception how to resolve this problem?
i set the timer for 10 secodns and call SlideShow() method..

```
private void SlideShow()
{
     if (animating == false)
         {
                animating = true;
                if (images.Count <= imgIndex)
                    imgIndex = 0;

                index = images.Count > imgIndex ? imgIndex : 0;

                imgIndex++;
                fadeOUT.From = 1;
                fadeOUT.To = 0;
                fadeOUT.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(CrossFadeTime);
                fadeOUT.Completed += new EventHandler(fadeIN_Completed);

                fadeIN.From = 0;
                fadeIN.To = 1;
                fadeIN.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(CrossFadeTime);
                fadeIN.Completed += new EventHandler(fadeIN_Completed);
                if (images[index].Contains(".wmv") || images[index].Contains(".mkv") || images[index].Contains(".mp4"))
                    myMediaElement.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
                else
                {
                    if (myMediaElement.Visibility == System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden)
                        myMediaElement.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                }

                myMediaElement.UnloadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
                myMediaElement.Stop();
                myMediaElement.Source = null;
                myMediaElement.Close();
                myMediaElement.Source = new Uri(images[index], UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                myMediaElement.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
                myMediaElement.Volume = 0;

                myMediaElement1.UnloadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
                myMediaElement1.Stop();
                myMediaElement1.Source = null;
                myMediaElement1.Close();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(900);
                myMediaElement1.Source = new Uri(images[images.Count > index + 1 ? index + 1 : 0], UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                myMediaElement1.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
                myMediaElement1.MediaOpened += myMediaElement1_MediaOpened;
                myMediaElement1.MediaEnded += myMediaElement1_MediaEnded;
                myMediaElement.BeginAnimation(Image.OpacityProperty, fadeOUT, HandoffBehavior.SnapshotAndReplace);
                myMediaElement1.BeginAnimation(Image.OpacityProperty, fadeIN, HandoffBehavior.SnapshotAndReplace);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to reduce memory consumption of application as much as possible until exception is gone.

You can decrease the memory consumption by just unregister the event when the child window closes.
For example:

```
    myMediaElement1.MediaEnded -= myMediaElement1_MediaEnded;
```

You can assign null to all MediaElement Properties once Begin Animation is completed and then start BeginAnimation of MediaElement1

```
     myMediaElement.Source=null;
     myMediaElement.UnloadedBehavior = null;  (if possible)
      .
      .
```

This [Link](http://svetoslavsavov.blogspot.com/2010/05/memory-leaks-in-wpf-applications.html) further elaborate  Memory Leaks

Comment: The problem isn't solved, Now video playing 5-6 hours and i get same exception again((